# codeigniter parser condition issue

Tags: codeigniter, parsing, conditional-statements

I have to change my project and to eliminate all PHP code in views. Project was written in CodeIgniter.

I achieved to eliminate php code with parser class, but that class doesn't have conditions (if, else, ..). Up to now I tried to install some template engine but without any success. Every tutorial is lack of one step or some steps are not clearly explained.

Can anyone help me and tell me in which way I should go or what to do. Maybe to explain me can I in controller already make all statement and just list what I need in view.

Comment: Can I check in controller for each row one field and adjust value?

Comment: What are you asking? Isn't the thing you're asking exactly what a controller should do?

Comment: How? If I list all data frome table and send to view, how in controller to change for particular column values 0 and 1 with active and disabled?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to eliminate all the php tags in your view

```
<?php //logic ?>
```

you can use smarty alone or with CI or other system like it. But you need to learn new sintax as php.

On the other hand, you can make your ogic in your controller (not recommended)

controller.php

```
function do_somthing(){
    $var_l = '<table>';
    $var_l .= '<thead>';
    $var_l .= '<th>uno</th>';
    $var_l .= '<th>dos</th>';
    $var_l .= '<th>tres</th>';
    $var_l .= '</thead>';
    $var_l .= '<tbody>';

    $a = array('a', 'b', 'c');

    foreach($a as $item){
        $var_l .= '<thc'.$item.'</th>';
    }

    $var_l .= '</tbody>';
    $var_l .= '</table>';

    $data['table'] = $var_l;

    $this->load->view('view', $data);
}
```

your view.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

info to display table

<?= $table ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed with regular parse in codeigniter, and done in this way:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
 <body>
  <?php echo $content ?>
 </body> 
</html>
```

And in controller like this:

```
    $query = $this->users_mod->allProducts();
    $data = array(
              'ap_heading' => 'Product definition',
              'ap_entries' => $query,
            );
    $content = $this->parser->parse('allproducts', $data, TRUE); 
    $this->load->view('template', compact('content'));
```

Can I somehow avoid this in controller: compact('content'), and php in view?